# Active Storage (stored in AWS S3) mobile uploaded image rotating on safari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, orientation, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails application which uses AWS S3 and active storage.

When an image is uploaded from mobile, it is rotating on Safari - it oriented successfully on Chrome mobile + Chrome desktop.

Chrome desktop:
[image: Chrome desktop]

Safari desktop:

[image: Safari desktop]

From doing some research (http://www.rubyflow.com/p/qqivs1-activestorage-variants-are-persisting-original-image-exif-metadata) I learnt about `auto_orient: true` so tried to add this but was not able to resolve this issue.

The current image tag is:

```
url(<%= rails_blob_url(tlk.image, resize: '800x300', auto_orient: true) %>
```

set as a background image of a `div`.

Unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: hmm doesn't appear to be working. I'm just checking on desktop right now, so maybe the images are cached? Any other idea?!

Comment: I ended up with something like `url(<%= url_for(image.variant(combine_options: { resize: ..., auto_orient: true, crop: ..., gravity: 'center' })) %>)`.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, that seemed to work. Do you know why?!

Comment: That's pretty much what the blog is doing (except they don't need `combine_options`). `rails_blob_url` is a normal path helper and maybe it doesn't understand the options you're using, but calling `variant` yourself, you get the image you want and then `url_for` knows how to convert that to a URL.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. I was wondering how .variant works in terms of performance. If I make a new variant, does it have to 'generate' every time the page loads, or does it save to my bucket so it can load without having to be generated first? Thank you again for your help

Comment: The variants should get stored, you should see them if you poke around the S3 bucket a bit. I've done my share of wrestling with ActiveStorage, nice to share the results :)